# Tizen Studio and SDB on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos-sierra, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-studio

After the migration of my development environment from El Capitan to Sierra and updating Tizen Studio from 1.0.1 to 1.1.1 the SDB CLI does not work any more on my new machine. I have installed JDK 1.8.0_121.

I can not really start a SDB server.

```
$ sdb devices
* server not running. starting it now on port 26099 *
fatal: server listener(26099) cannot bind
```

Then the following is returned:

```
* server started successfully *
```

But I can not connect to devices or list them:

```
$ sdb devices
```

runs into endless loop without feedback.

I have tested also the old Tizen Studio version 1.0.1 but got the same result. Can this be a Java or MacOS problem?

Any hints what can be the problem?

Comment: Check your firewall settings(stop it for some time), port blocking, try to connect keeping minimum distance. Use static ip instead of dynamic. Reset you device. Clear all log of previously connected devices.

Comment: I also encounter same issue in MacOs Mojave

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with SDB and probably Mac OS Sierra.
I have downgraded to Smart Development Bridge version 2.2.67 and sdb works fine. All newer version occur the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to kill the process that sdb cannot bind and then start sdb again with `sdb start-server`

To find out what process port 26099 is taking

`sudo lsof -i:26099`

The output

```
COMMAND  PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sdb     3495 lucasbatista    5u  IPv4 0x401834fdf37019a7      0t0  TCP *:26099 (LISTEN)
```

To kill the process

`kill <pid>`

In this case

`kill 3495`

Note:

I realized that the process that occupies this port, is usually the emulator itself when we started with Tizen Studio.

Now, I don't know why sdb simply does not choose another port to start or the emulator does not start on another port, since the developers of Tizen Studio, must have the knowledge that the default sdb port is 26099

Anyway, this step by step that I mentioned above, works for me, I hope it works for you too